# Hill Cipher Encryption error with Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to implement Encryption with Hill Cipher, the code correctly encrypts the letters AC from ACT but the letter T is converted to U which is wrong. Can i know what is wrong in this code?

I'm following the example given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hill-cipher/)

Expected Output: ACT-->POH
Current Output: ACT-->POU

```js
//Generates ASCII values of characters
const generateAscii=(string)=>{
    string=string.split('').map((value)=>{
        return value.charCodeAt();
    });
    return string;
};
//Generates characters from ASCII value
const generateChars=(ascii)=>{
    ascii=ascii.map(value=>String.fromCharCode(value));
    console.log(ascii);//Final Output generated here
};
//Encryption
const encrypt=(input,key)=>{
    let matrix=[];
    let cipherAscii=[];
    //Matrix creation
    for(let i in input){
        let values=key.splice(0,input.length);
        matrix.push(values);
    }
    //Matrix multiplication and encryption
    for (let i of matrix){
        let sum=0;
        for(let j in i){
            sum+=i[j]*input[j];
        }
        cipherAscii.push(((sum-65)%26)+65);
    }
    return cipherAscii;
};
    let input='ACT';
    let key='GYBNQKURP';
    let encryptedValues;
    input=generateAscii(input)
    key=generateAscii(key);
    encryptedValues=encrypt(input,key);
    let encryptedText=generateChars(encryptedValues);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the changes where I changed to fix issue:

```
const generateAscii=(string)=>{
string=string.split('').map((value)=>{
    return value.charCodeAt()-65;
});
return string;
};
```

And,

```
for (let i of matrix){
        let sum=0;
        for(let j in i){
            sum+=i[j]*input[j];
    }
    cipherAscii.push(((sum)%26)+65);
}
```

Now, what was issue in your code:

**You have changed char to ASCII instead of whole number. So while doing matrix multiplication that number is multiplied by X that means 65 is also increased in the same way.This approach is rather complex to maintain.
But, it is easier if we initially decrease by 65 then compute and increase 65 in output.**

You might have got gist of it what was the issue.

Comment: Solves my issue with a good explanation..Thank you for guidance!